# Is it possible to enter emojis directly using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, input-source, emoji

I would like to enter emojis directly from the keyboard. E.g. that I type ‘:D’ and it gets converted to ‘’. Is that possible?

I know about the control + command + space shortcut to open the emoji palette, but I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: You can always bodge together 14 regular keyboards as Tom Scott does in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AtBE9BOvvk. Not sure if it's possible on a Mac, but this is how he does it on Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Text and set as many replacements as you wish.

Set the ‘Replace’ to the standard characters and the ‘With’ to the emoji you would like the ‘Replace’ to be replaced with.

These synchronise over iCloud, so will be available on your iOS devices too.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice application called [Rocket](http://matthewpalmer.net/rocket/) which enables you the *Slack*-way of typing emojis:

You type `:` (colon) followed by the emoji's name and it offers a popover with autocompletions.

[image: Rocket demonstration]